# Find upserted keys in Cassandra columnfamily within time interval

Tags: cassandra, cql, pycassa

Is it possible to get the list of affected keys in a cassandra column family within a time interval.Cassandra does maintain column level timestamps. Can it be leveraged somehow ?

I have a simple columnfamily (key, value) and I want to know which keys were updated/inserted in the last one day. Unfortunately, I can't modify the column family to include a timestamp column and index it, as is generally advised. Does anyone have any other thoughts/hacks on how can this problem be tackled ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't modify the table you have to scan the whole table across the cluster.
In CQL 3 and later you can write

```
SELECT key, value, WRITETIME(value) FROM kvtable;
```

This is the only way and it's very onerous to the cluster

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks @Carlo. I think under the circumstances this looks the best option :)